# Linq2Sql: Generically select 2 fields based on given expression

Tags: c#, generics, linq-to-entities

I am trying to implement a dynamic repository of Entity Framework. I notice that we use a lot of this pattern:

```
public Dictionary<int, string> SelectSomething(IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    return entity
            .Table
            .Where(t => ids.Contains(t.IdField))
            .Select(t => new {t.IdField, t.ValueField})
            .ToDictionary(k => kIdField, v => v.ValueField);
}
```

Basically, select and return a dictionary with Id fits some condition.

I am trying to rewrite this method generically. So far I've got the signature:

```
Dictionary<TKey, TValue> GetEntityKeyValue<TEntity, TKey, TValue>(   
        Expression<Func<TEntity, TKey>> keyExpression, 
        Expression<Func<TEntity, TValue>> valueExpression, 
        Expression<Func<TKey, bool>> keyPredicate)

        where TEntity : class
{ ... }
```

Basically, so that I can call

```
var valueDict = GetEntityKeyValue<tbl_table, int, string>(t => t.IdField, t.ValueField, id => id > 1);
```

Please help me write the **GetEntityKeyValue** method. I know it would involve dynamtic expression somehow, but I don't know how to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select` statement is not needed, moreover it creates projection to anonymous type, that leads to corresponding `Expression` building requirement:

```
public Dictionary<TKey, TValue> GetEntityKeyValue<TEntity, TKey, TValue>
(
    Func<TEntity, TKey> keySelector,
    Func<TEntity, TValue> valueSelector,
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> keyPredicate
) where TEntity : class
{
    return context.Set<TEntity>().Where(keyPredicate)
                  .ToDictionary(keySelector, valueSelector);
}
```

Comment: I tried it out and VS is complaining about the ToDictionary(). I think it's because I need to do a .Select(i => {key, value}) first. How do I do that? I am using EF 6.2 btw

Comment: What is complaint?

Comment: Nvm I figure it out, I need to compile it: Context.Set<TEntity>().Where(keyCondition).ToDictionary(keySelector.Compile(), valueSelector.Compile()). I am marking you answer as accepted.

Comment: @NamNgo, to eliminate `Compile()` you can change method's signature from `Expression<Func<>>` to simple `Func<>` for key and value selectors.

Comment: What if I want to replace keyPredicate with an Array<TKey>.Contains() method? How would I translate GetEntityKeyValue to take an array instead of the keyPredicate?

Comment: All remain the same: `keyPredicate = x => array.Contains(x.Id)`, or you can take `array` as parameter and then `.Where(x => array.Contains(x.Id))`